# AirParrot2 (Screen mirroring software) - Unable to connect to Kodi device

Tags: windows-10, raspberry-pi, mirroring, kodi

**Introduction**

What I am trying to do is mirror my Windows 10 screen to my TV in another room. I have Kodi installed on a raspberry pi that is connected to this TV. Kodi supports apple airplay. I have successfully played videos over apple airplay using PlayOn software from my computer so I know the apple airplay part works with at least one piece of software. PlayOn doesn't support mirroring the entire screen though and only does video windows.

**Problem**

I have tried a few different programs, including AirParrot 2 which appear like they should work across a plethora of devices. Every time they search on my network for supported devices, they do find my raspberry pi listed as "Kodi". However, whenever I actually connect they always fail. In AirParrot's case, the connecting icon just spins for hours with no connection happening.

*I am of course open to other programs but my question is not focused on that aspect.* It seems that the different programs I have tried never can connect so there must be something I am consistently doing wrong.. perhaps something not setup correctly on Kodi? I thought just enabling ZeroConfig and Airplay was all that is needed.

FYI my version of Kodi is Isengard (15.1) and I have Windows 10 on my computer I am trying to broadcast. The raspberry pi is connected to my network via ethernet cable, as my computer is as well.

Comment: Your Kodi version is ancient but that's not the issue. Kodi by default does not accept such connections, it must be enabled in settings (and enabling AirPlay isn't enough). Unfortunately I can't be of much help with that because the current version I'm using is totally different. In 17.5 you'd click the cog wheel then "Service Settings" > "Control" and enable "allow control from applications on other systems"

Comment: BTW, your title is quite misleading. Later you say *they do find my raspberry pi listed as "Kodi"* so... Kodi is found after all. The problem is it refuses the connection as it does by default.

Comment: @MichaelBay I guess I haven't been looking for quite some time for updates. Perhaps you are on to something though. I will try to update my Kodi to a later version. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelBay So I updated my Kodi to the latest version and the same problem. I am at Krypton 17.5 now. I have "allow control from applications on other systems" turned on too.